# how to call parent page javascript from iframe inside an update panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, updatepanel

What i am trying to do is i want to call a javascript function in the parent page to scroll the window to the TOP. I have one master page with a JS function "top" for scrolling page to the top, inside Master Page there is updatepanel and inside update panel there is iframe.Every time when iframe loads i want the masterpage to be on top.

Solutions i have tried:

but i am getting compile time error tht onload cant be added to iframe becz it is inside an update panel

i know my question is not very clear.still expecting some response.

Answer (score 0):

*Assumption:* both the iframe and parent window are from the same domain.

You can do this to retrieve the reference to the iframe's parent DOM element:

```
var iframeParent = window.parent.document;
```

With that reference, you can access the parent's functions that are in the global scope, so in your case the "top function" for scrolling the page?

Comment: yea both are on same domain.

you mean to say i should make a call something like this from the page inside the iframe: <body onload="loadme()"> 
and loadme() function should contain window.parent.document.top_function(); is it the correct way???

Comment: @madhur Access `window.parent.document` from the context within your iframe.

Comment: yea it got that but how to call that function from that page loaded inside the iframe?? iframeParent.functionname(); ??

Comment: Yes. Your function would have to be defined in the global namespace in order to be accessed this way. You can check by typing in your browser developer JavaScript console: `this` or `window` See if your function is listed in there (that's the global namespace).